# Media Queries not working (horizontal website)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm making this horizontal website, and i'm using 2 screens: one 1920x1080, one 1600x900.

This is my css, i want that for screens smaller than 1650px the element width be 65%, and for bigger screens 71%.

```
.mejs-time-rail{width:71% !important;}
@media (max-width:1650px;){
.mejs-time-rail{width:65% !important;}
```

And this is in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

But it's not working, on 1600px screen the element doesn't even call this:

```
.mejs-time-rail{width:65% !important;}
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening?

The website is: http://www.arturhaddad.com/inky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no semicolons in media queries...

Comment: ...also in the script you posted you forgot to close the media query tag using }